# Samsung / Android 8.0 Oreo update causing app(s) to crash? (Xamarin.Forms app)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-8.0-oreo, samsung-galaxy

Has anyone else experienced a high number of app crashes with Samsung / Android 8.0 Oreo update?

We've seen a huge spike in crashes specific to Samsung devices running Android 8.0 Oreo and after doing some Googling it seems to be a common problem (search: **Samsung Oreo app crash**)

[image: crash log (not useful)]
[image]

To resolve, the user either has to restart their device, perform a soft reset or clear the cache data for the app.

Is there a way to prevent these crashes? I've thought about attempting to clear the cache pragmatically to see if that helps.

FYI - I've posted the same question on Xamarin.Forms: [Xamarin.Forms Link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/139088/samsung-android-8-0-oreo-update-causing-crashes/p1?new=1)

Any thoughts or solutions most welcome!

Comment: The cache data is 100% your app's data so you should know if what is in it is causing problems (I.e. a file containing serialized objects that are no longer valid, etc...)

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  The Oreo update has affected many apps (Instagram, FB, Snap Chat etc) and it's specific to Samsung only.  We don't see this issue on Android 7.0, 7.1 or 8.1, it's specific to users updating to Oreo 8.0.  There are dozens of articles on how to fix apps that crash (aimed at users) telling them to restart their device, re-install apps and clear app cache.  I've spoken with a few users who say clearing the cache resolves the problem therefore I think a solution would be to clear the cache pragmatically on app exit / launch or upon an update?

Comment: I understand the point, I've dealt with many OEM/device specific issues before (there can be a lot of differences between the different OEM releases and ASOP and Samsung is one OEM that makes heavy changes to the ASOP source) and as an example if you have serialized data, you are caching it and an OEM update changes something that invalidates your serialized data, your app may crash on that device now...   What is the sigsegv crash's thread stack reported in `logcat`? and have you symbolized the crash?

Comment: Thanks Sushi.  Unfortunately we're unable to re-create the crashing with our own device and only have the crash logs in Android Google Play Console and there is little to no data within them.  The majority of the crashes are signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR) or code 1 (SEGV_ACCERR).

Comment: Quick question: Are these crashes on just Samsung Mali based GPU devices, just wondering as user code based seq-faults revolving around the GPU driver (mali0) are null reference issues in View/ViewGroups .

Comment: The crashes are only reported for Samsung Galaxy S8 (dreamlte), Galaxy S8+ (dream2lte), Galaxy Note8 (greatlte) all running Android Oreo 8.0.  All other Android OS versions are not affected and no other devices are reported.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? We have a ticket open with Microsoft for a similar issue. No idea what causes it but they were saying it happens during app update.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using firebase library? Did you try to update to the latest version? I did it and I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is still experiencing similar issue on European Samsung Oreo devices (SIGSEV during startup): 
In most cases, methods that cause crash are file/memory related, but "it's not their fault".
There are issues regarding startup stability on Samsung Oreo update if you are **not targeting primary ABI for device**. For Xamarin, in visual studio -> Project properties -> android options ->advanced -> supported architecture and make sure arm64-v8a (primary ABI for S8, Note8 where bug occurs.) is checked. 
That should solve it.